# Firebase functions download file from storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I'm using a Firebase function to generate a PDF (pdfkit) with images stored in Storage. I only have the public url of the image. The function and the Storage are part of the same account/project in Firebase.

How can I download the image in a temp location to generate my pdf? I have tried the following code (and some variation but none worked) It cannot find the file/image.

```
const tmpFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'tmp.jpg');
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
await bucket.file(imageURL).download({destination: tmpFilePath});
doc.image(tmpFilePath, x, y);
fs.unlinkSync(tmpFilePath);
```

Comment: are you seeing any error in logs? please add it on the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just answering my own question for future reference and help others.
I could not make the download working with the url so I modify the code to store the local path and use this one instead.

```
async function WriteImage(doc:any, storagePath:string, topX:number, topY:number, width:number, height:number, name:string){
    doc.rect(topX, topY, width, height).stroke('#000');
    if(storagePath !== null){
        const tmpPath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'tmp.jpg');
        await admin.storage().bucket().file(storagePath).download({destination: tmpPath});
        doc.image(tmpPath, topX, topY, {fit: [width, height]});
        fs.unlinkSync(tmpPath);
}
```

}